# Video As A Background. Navigation not Fixed

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, video

I've already posted this on the theme's author support page. I haven't gotten an answer yet.

Video plugin: jQuery.videoBG
theme: Mercurial
site: [wearehmc.com/wordpress/](http://wearehmc.com/wordpress/)

Right now, the site is set up with video as a background. I have figured that it’s not the plugin, but the theme  because it works on the current site with a fixed navigation.

So, as I said the navigation header “unstickies” it’s self in Chrome, Safari, and Opera (there’s also some weird behavior too). I haven’t even tried IE … But really I’m not worried about IE, yet. There’s no weird CSS changes, or Javascript errors.

Now it might have something to do with it calling different videos for the different browsers, but as I said before, the static site that we have up at the moment works fine, and if I remember correctly Firefox and Safari support the same video format.

Oh, and when the navigation header is set to absolute there’s no weird behavior.

I'm trying to figure out if this is a html5 video bug, or a theme bug.

What I would like not have to do: Change video plugins.

Comment: Is there a link to the page you're working on?

Comment: yes. [link](http://wearehmc.com/wordpress/)

Comment: So I've been trying figure this out, even tried a few different videoBG type plugins. Still nothing.